# What is this metal thing under my passenger seat?

Tags: mazda, part-identification, mazda-3

In my Mazda 3 BL (manufactered 2010, version for EU) there is this (see picture) metal thing under my passenger seat, what is it?

Same thing is also under the drivers seat.[image]

Comment: Looks like a vent outlet - does air come out of it when you turn the fan on?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: AKA a toe-slicer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @NickC said in comments. That is a vent tube for your HVAC air to flow through. Usually these are pointed at the back seats so they get some of that action.